# WPF Bindings : Editing a value in a TextBox inside a DataTemplate that displays that same value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I want to create a debug window that will allow us to edit properties from various objects in our app while it runs. This will allow us, for example, to tweak threshold values for certain heuristic rules in our app, without requiring a rebuild and/or app restart.

The goal is to tell the debug window to enable editing some property of an object. The window then obtains the property's value, keeps a weak reference to the object and displays an appropriate data template (based on the value's type) to enable us to edit the value and apply the new value to the object when needed.

**Problem:**

The data templates are applied correctly and the value is displayed for each debug item in a `TextBox`. However, the `Value` property of each `DebugItem`, to which the `TextBox` is bound, is *NEVER* updated. I have set a breakpoint on that property's setter; the breakpoint is never triggered.

**Here is my current setup:**

- I have a `DebugItems` collection of `DebugItem` objects in my view model.
- Each `DebugItem` has a `Value` property of type `object`.
- For debugging purposes, the `Value` property always contains a string.
- I have created a data template for the `DebugItem` type and the `System:String` type.
- My window contains a `ListBox` that is bound to the `DebugItems` collection and displays `DebugItem`s using the data template defined above, in a ContentPresenter. A `TextBox` inside that data template is *also* bound to the `Value` so that it enables us to edit the string value using the other, `System:String` data template defined above ***.

*** I am under the impression that this has to do with why the edit doesn't work. I could be mistaken, through.

**Relevant part of the window:**

```
<Grid Background="#CECECE">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DebugItems}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**My data template:**

(Of particular interest are the inner `ContentPresenter` and its embedded `System:String` data template.)

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Debug:DebugItem}">
    <Grid Height="60" d:DesignWidth="403.06">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="181*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="14,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Value}" Height="Auto">
                <ContentPresenter.Resources>

                    <!-- String -->
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
            </ContentPresenter>
            <UniformGrid Grid.Column="2" Rows="1">
                <Button Margin="8,8,0.5,8" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" Content="Update" />
                <Button Margin="4.5,8,8,8" Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" Content="Apply" />
            </UniformGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your DebugItem a struct? If that's a value type user interface might be dealing with another copy you don't have

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that's not it.